# Making Existing Userlevel program root?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, root

Is it possible to give root to an already running application which runs at userspace?

Like `x` program is running, I did some unsaveable work on `x` program, But it needs root to complete. I do not want to restart the `x` program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

What you have to do is save the work somewhere you **can** write to, e.g. `/tmp`, exit the program, run the program with `sudo  x`, and read the data from `/tmp`.

Or, in `vi` or `vim`, you can do `:w | sudo tee root-writeable-file`